# How can I avoid a deadlock with this single UPDATE statement, even when using TABLOCKX?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, deadlock

I have a pretty good handle on dealing and resolving deadlocks with the help of Trace flag 1222 and TABLOCKX has been helpful.  I'm seeing a new deadlock that I don't understand why it's deadlocking, and how to fix it.  I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2, 10.50.2861.0.

This single statement is in a transaction all by itself (with explicit BEGIN/COMMIT statements which I realize are not needed).  Based on the deadlock trace (flag 1222), this statement is holding a lock on `TableB` trying to get a lock on `TableA`.  TableC is inconsequential.

I would have thought that SQL Server would not start processing this statement until it could gain an exclusive table lock on both `TableA` and `TableB`.  If it did that, I would expect it to hold off doing anything (be blocked) until it could gain exclusive locks on both tables.  Instead it appears that SQL Server is starting off reading `TableB` (and locking it) before it gets to `TableA`, and then when it gets to `TableA` it is finding itself deadlocked with another process (a different SQL statement) that has a lock on `TableA` and that other process is trying to insert data into `TableB`.  This other process is not using any TABLOCKX.

Is my interpretation of this correct?  How can I get SQL Server to lock both tables before running this statement to avoid a deadlock?

```
UPDATE a
SET StatusId = 9,
    StatusLastUpdatedOn = GETDATE()
FROM dbo.TableA AS a WITH (TABLOCKX)
INNER JOIN dbo.TableC AS c ON c.StatusId = a.StatusId       
WHERE c.IsComplete = 0
AND   a.StatusId NOT IN (1, 3)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.TableB AS b WITH (TABLOCKX)
    WHERE b.Value1 = a.Value1
    AND   b.ConditionA = 1
);
```

EDIT, per request from @Bogdan Sahlean, below is the TF1222 output - with the longer statements abbreviated.  The above UPDATE statement is process4583288.  It's deadlocking with process459d708.  It appears the above UPDATE statement (process4583288) is the owner of `TableB` and waiting to gain access to `TableA`.

```
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,waiter id=process459d708 mode=IS requestType=wait
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,waiter-list
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,owner id=process4583288 mode=X
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,owner-list
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,objectlock lockPartition=0 objid=980471563 subresource=FULL dbid=11 objectname=dbname.dbo.TableB id=lock9e7bc880 mode=X associatedObjectId=980471563
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,waiter id=process4583288 mode=X requestType=wait
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,waiter-list
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,owner id=process459d708 mode=IX
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,owner-list
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,objectlock lockPartition=0 objid=353147353 subresource=FULL dbid=11 objectname=dbname.dbo.TableA id=lock3f439dc80 mode=IX associatedObjectId=353147353
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,resource-list
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 11 Object Id = 1385795344]
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,inputbuf
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,EXEC dbo.usp_ProcedureB;
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,frame procname=dbname.dbo.usp_ProcedureD line=127 stmtstart=6586 stmtend=7022 sqlhandle=0x03000b00108f9952edd5580183a200000100000000000000
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,*** This is the INSERT statement that is deadlocking with the UPDATE statement posted in the Stackoverflow Question - shortened ***
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,frame procname=dbname.dbo.usp_ProcedureB line=119 stmtstart=4972 stmtend=9598 sqlhandle=0x03000b00eb973e0a22e7ee007da200000100000000000000
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,executionStack
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,process id=process459d708 taskpriority=0 logused=236 waitresource=OBJECT: 11:980471563:0  waittime=2127 ownerId=23648431472 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2013-12-11T13:11:07.233 XDES=0x27a62c3b0 lockMode=IS schedulerid=4 kpid=2788 status=suspended spid=61 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2013-12-11T13:11:07.233 lastbatchcompleted=2013-12-11T13:11:07.223 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=IP-0AF81DC9 hostpid=5388 loginname=some-user isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=23648431472 currentdb=11 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=673185824 clientoption2=128056
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 11 Object Id = 200150858]
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,inputbuf
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,EXEC dbo.usp_ProcedureA;
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,frame procname=dbname.dbo.usp_ProcedureC line=56 stmtstart=2452 stmtend=2616 sqlhandle=0x03000b004a0fee0be3f6ee007da200000100000000000000
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,*** This is the UPDATE statement Statement Posted in the Stackoverflow Question - shortened ***
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,frame procname=dbname.dbo.usp_ProcedureA line=148 stmtstart=7390 stmtend=8462 sqlhandle=0x03000b00806122731562150182a200000100000000000000
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,executionStack
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,process id=process4583288 taskpriority=0 logused=0 waitresource=OBJECT: 11:353147353:0  waittime=2170 ownerId=23648431512 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2013-12-11T13:11:07.240 XDES=0x17d90d950 lockMode=X schedulerid=3 kpid=1164 status=suspended spid=66 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2013-12-11T13:11:07.030 lastbatchcompleted=2013-12-11T13:11:07.030 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=IP-0AF81DC9 hostpid=5388 loginname=some-user isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=23648431512 currentdb=11 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=673185824 clientoption2=128056
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,process-list
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,deadlock victim=process4583288
12/11/2013 13:11:09,spid19s,Unknown,deadlock-list
```

Comment: Please post the output of TF1222. Based on this output somebody can say if the interpretation is correct or wrong.

Comment: Locking X an entire table just to avoid deadlocks is *usually* a bad solution.

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean, I edited my question, including the TF1222 output. I understand TABLOCKX is not the first thing you want to do and typically I don't use them, but without them, I was getting all sorts of deadlocks on some tables that are read and updated very frequently, and have mostly solved them with a combination of reducing the number of statements in a transaction among other things, and have found TABLOCKX to help in a few places.  I'd rather have a short amount of blocking than a deadlock.

Comment: TABLOCKX has a negative impact on concurrency. This hint locks eXclusive a entire table. This could remove some DLs but this doesn't means this is the solution. It's just a way to avoid the real problem and not to remove that problem.

Comment: Could you post also the execution plans (estimated or , better, the actual execution plans) for these two stored procedures: EXEC dbo.usp_ProcedureB & EXEC dbo.usp_ProcedureA ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, I appreciate the help. I have the execution plans, but for now am happy with the more generic advice and am likely going to make a couple of adjustments either by serializing the processes or rearranging the code.  I agree that TABLOCKX has a negative impact, but deadlocks are a worse impact.  These queries generally run very fast (200ms-300ms) and I'd rather one be blocked for 100-300ms than deadlock.  At the same time, TABLOCKX is typically a last resort for me, and am in full agreement it's not an ideal solution.  If this one continues be problematic, I'll post back.

Comment: A deadlock is a reflection of a performance issue. Using these x locks will hide these issues,instead  of resolving them. Just an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't acquire all the locks in advance, i.e. after coming up with a query plan and before starting to reading the data. It just goes through the query plan, executing its parts in order that is neede and acquiring the locks when they are needed. In your example, it has to execute the inner query first so it gets the lock on `TableB` before it later tries to get a lock on `TableA`.

I'm not sure if there's a universal way of avoiding deadlocks in such situations. You can minimize its chance, maybe by putting two `select top 1 * from ... WITH (TABLOCKX)` (one for each table) at the top of your transaction. As they would be executed very quickly, there would be less chance of something getting in between.

Comment: It's too bad that it works like this, thanks for making me aware.  Not a bad idea of adding those dummy TABLOCKX statements up top. Those too seem like they could deadlock but because they run so fast, less chances.

Comment: This reminds me of something else I've done in the past where I have a separate, helper table with a row in it that in the very beginning of a transaction, I'll run a dummy update on with UPDLOCK.  Any other processes that try to run the same transaction/procedure will get blocked on that until the first process commits.  In this case, they are separate procedures, but both procedures could run the same update on that single row in the helper table, effectively serializing access to TableA and TableB.  I'd rather not jump thru so many hoops if possible, but is still better than deadlocks.

Comment: Yes, that could be possible too. Another way is to capture deadlocks and rerun the whole thing. Repeated deadlocks are much less likely.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to reduce the chance of a deadlock is to make sure the queries run fast.

Before changing the behavior of sql server (e.g. changing Locking mode level etc) I would make sure that the queries involved in the deadlock are well optimized.

Comment: Good tip thanks.  I did find one of the queries benefited from a new index, which I added after posting this question.  Around a 100-200ms drop in execution time which is still substantial and the index will help even more as the amount of data increases.  The two queries are running around 50-200ms each, so not too shabby.

Comment: One more thing that could prevent deadlocks is to have both queries access table A and table B in the same order. So you could potentially consider tweaking the other query to access table B first (same as the deadlock victim)